# Conversion to Mono on a Mac

Tags: .net, macos, mono, pinvoke

I have a project written .NET 2.0 (well, it doesn't use much in the way of 3.5 features, anyway), and I recently got a Mac and would like to convert that project to Mono.

The problem is, this project relies on libraries such as [FreeImage](http://freeimage.sourceforge.net/) and a few C++ libraries I've written for this project.  I'm a total newb to programming on the Mac; how can I link these libraries into this project so that the p/invoke calls don't fail?  I can compile all the libraries again if need be, so what format should I put the libraries in, and is there any particular tool I should be using?  When coding on the Visual Studio side, I just had the libraries as projects in the same solution as the .NET code.  Does a similar setup exist on the Mac?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This [page](http://www.mono-project.com/Interop_with_Native_Libraries) might be helpful.  Explains how Interop works on OS X (and other operating systems).

Comment: Thanks! From looking it over briefly, it looks like the Right Thing-- I'll know more once I try to make it work.